# Getting a branch name I work on with GitHub Webhook on Pull Requests

Tags: python, git, github-api, webhooks

I am trying to get all the details from a WebHook trigger when labelling a Pull Request on Git Hub. 
I am getting a lot of info with the payload but the one thing I really need is the Branch name I work on that has the Pull Request I opened.

In GitHub page I see:
Pavel wants to merge 2 commits into master from  <-- I'd like to obtain that branch name somehow..
Thanks!

Comment: can you please screen grab what you're talking about for more clearity?

Answer (score 4):

So I solved it this way, even though there may be a better way..

content is the payload json that I receive with the WebHook.

pull_request_url is the url of the PR I am working on.

pr_content is the json I am receiving when I am calling the PR url.

From there I just extract the branch name from the pr_content json

```
def get_branch_name(content):
    pull_request_url = content['pull_request']['_links']['self']['href']
    pr_content = get(pull_request_url)
    if pr_content.status_code == 200:
        branch_name = (pr_content.json()['head']['label']).split(":")[1]
    else:
        branch_name = 'master'
    return branch_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation of the pull request event:
https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent

You want to filter out events where `action` is `labeled`.

Then you have the target branch in `$.base.ref` and the source branch in `$.head.ref`.

And if you want to do this in Jenkins, I can suggest https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Below methods worked for me. PS: tested on *CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 2.263.2.3-rolling*

In **descriptive pipeline**, I am using below code in stages > stage block

```
    stage ('stage_name') {
        steps {
            echo 'hello from common section'
            echo "BRANCH_NAME: ${env.GIT_BRANCH.split("/")[1]}"
        }
    }
```